# Having trouble with array_map when handling $_POST data

Tags: php, wordpress, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I'm working on updating some code that calls a function based on post data. The original class looks like this:

```
class RegistrationProceduresController
{
    public function __construct($username, $password, $host, $port, $dbname)
    {
        $SP = new RegistrationProceduresModel($username, $password, $host, $port, $dbname);

        if(method_exists($SP, $SP->$_POST['function']()))
        {
            $SP->$_POST['function']();
        }
        else
        {
            die("Function does not exist" . isnull($SP->$_POST['function'](), ". No function was specified"));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update this class to sanitize the data before executing a function based on post data. So far I've come to the following:

```
class RegistrationProceduresController
{
    public function __construct($username, $password, $host, $port, $dbname)
    {
        $SP = new RegistrationProceduresModel($username, $password, $host, $port, $dbname);

        // Sanitize all the incoming data
        $sanitized = array_map('sanitize', $_POST);

        if(method_exists($SP, $SP->$sanitized['function']()))
        {
            $SP->$sanitized['function']();
        }
        else
        {
            die("Function does not exist" . isnull($SP->$sanitized['function'](), ". No function was specified"));
        }
    }

    public function sanitize($input)
    {
        return htmlspecialchars(trim($input));
    }
}
```

This brings me to the following:

> Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   function 'sanitize' not found or invalid function name in
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\junglegym\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\qcore\qcore_waitress.php
>   on line 17Fatal error: Method name must be a string in
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\junglegym\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\qcore\qcore_waitress.php
>   on line 19

Which is this line:

```
if(method_exists($SP, $SP->$sanitized['function']()))
```

I perhaps incorrectly thought this would be how I could use my new variable (`$santized`) but it looks like I'm totally wrong. What would be the most efficient way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an object method, not a native function, as the `array_map` callback parameter. Try calling `array_map` like this:

```
$sanitized = array_map(array($this, 'sanitize'), $_POST);
```

See [Callbacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for more info.

`method_exists` just needs a string of the method name as its second parameter, try calling it like:

```
method_exists($SP, $sanitized['function']);
```

Comment: This comes back with the following:  

 Catchable fatal error: Object of class RegistrationProceduresController could not be converted to string in C:\DWASFiles\Sites\junglegym\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\qcore\qcore_waitress.php on line 21

Comment: Sorry - that was me! Fixed!